# IBM Application Center Install button on iOS

Tags: worklight-appcenter

To publish our application inside the enterprise, we are using IBM Application Centre that comes with the WL (We are running WL Enterprise Edition 6.2.0.1).

On iOS devices, When we click on "install" button, our application gets installed on the devices. However, the "install" button should change its value to " uninstall" which it doesn't, not like Android devices where it does change.

How can we fix this issue on iOS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.

In iOS it is not possible to determine whether an application is installed or not, and so the "Install" label cannot be altered to "Uninstall" like in Android.

Comment: The reason of my question that our QA team has assigned it as a defect and I just to confirm that this is the normal behaviour on iOS, am I right?

Comment: It is not a defect. This is by design.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation. Will remove the defect from our system.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. iOS does not allow to uninstall applications programatically or to test which applications are installed (since IBM Application Center is not an MDM technology). Therefore it makes no sense to change the button to "Uninstall" since it would not be functional.

The documentation about uninstalling applications states in [the user manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/appcenter/t_removing_an_installed_applicat.html)

- iOS: You can remove applications only from the iOS Home screen, and not through the Application Center client. Use the normal iOS procedure for removing an application.

Hence, an "Uninstall" button would make no sense.

Comment: Thank you Georg for the clarification.